# WSL can't see environment variable

Tags: c++, environment-variables, clion, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm currently on the quest to getting a MIPS cross-compiler toolchain running within WSL, accessed by CLion.

There, I'm having a strange issue with WSL. I have added the following to the `.bashrc`:

```
STAGING_DIR="/home/max/source/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-5.4.0_musl-1.1.16"
export STAGING_DIR
```

Moreover I have the script `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Staging dir is: " $STAGING_DIR
```

When using `wsl` to get a shell and execute the script, the output is as follows:

```
max@DESKTOP-ISH7UJQ:/mnt/c/Users/Maxi$ ./test.sh
Staging dir is:  /home/max/source/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-5.4.0_musl-1.1.16
```

When using `wsl <command>` to execute a bash command within WSL, the output differs. The environment variable has simply dissappeared.

```
C:\Users\Maxi>wsl ./test.sh
Staging dir is:
```

It seems like the `.bashrc` (I've also tried `.profile`) is not executed when executing it via wsl?`

This is a problem because when CLion invokes the WSL subsystem to build my C++ project using CMake, the compiler complains that this environment variable isn't there.

When I manually get a shell and execute the *exact same* cmake command, compilation works without warnings since the environment variable is there.

Inside CLion:

```
/usr/bin/cmake --build /mnt/c/Users/Maxi/CLionProjects/linux_wsl_test/cmake-build-debug-wsl_omega --target all -- -j 2
Scanning dependencies of target linux_wsl_test
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/linux_wsl_test.dir/main.cpp.o
mipsel-openwrt-linux-g++: warning: environment variable 'STAGING_DIR' not defined
[100%] Linking CXX executable linux_wsl_test
mipsel-openwrt-linux-g++: warning: environment variable 'STAGING_DIR' not defined
mipsel-openwrt-linux-g++: warning: environment variable 'STAGING_DIR' not defined
[100%] Built target linux_wsl_test
```

On a WSL shell:

```
max@DESKTOP-ISH7UJQ:~/build_dir$ /usr/bin/cmake --build /mnt/c/Users/Maxi/CLionProjects/linux_wsl_test/cmake-build-debug-wsl_omega --target all -- -j 2
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/linux_wsl_test.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable linux_wsl_test
[100%] Built target linux_wsl_test
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Try the test.sh with `bash.exe`.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Gives same empty result: `bash.exe -c "./test.sh" Staging dir is:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *~/.bashrc* file is only loaded by interactive shells. When you run your script in that fashion it is handled by a non-interactive shell. You can force it to be interactive by using the `-i` switch (although I don't know if that works with the `wsl` command). Alternatively, put `BASH_ENV=/home/max/.bashrc` in your environment before running the script.

Comment: `bash.exe -i -c "./test.sh"` gives `Staging dir is:  /home/max/source/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-5.4.0_musl-1.1.16`. This is the right track. I'll try your suggestion later this day.

Comment: Adding `set(ENV{BASH_ENV} "/home/max/.bashrc")` to my `CMakeList.txt` solved the problem.