# CMake cannot find environment variables within WSL

Tags: cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Cmake cannot find an environment variable defined in /etc/profile from within WSL.

I've tried putting the variable in other file such as /etc/environment but could not get it to echo in WSL. Finally using /etc/profile I get an echo.

/etc/environment

```
TEST="/some/path"
echo $TEST
>>
```

/etc/profile

```
TEST="/some/path"
echo $TEST
>>/some/path
```

My CMakeLists.txt has the following lines:

```
set(TEST $ENV{TEST})
message(STATUS "Output: ${TEST}")
```

When building, it outputs

```
>>Output:
```

This question had a similar issue : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52504895/wsl-cant-see-environment-variable). Nonetheless I've already tried using bash.exe -i. Also tried setting the next line in my CMakeLists.txt

```
set(ENV{BASH_ENV}"~/.bashrc")
```

Comment: So, how **exactly** you run `cmake`? The [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52504895/wsl-cant-see-environment-variable) tells about running via `wsl <command>`. Do you use that approach?

Comment: I do: **CXX=g++-7 CC=gcc-7 cmake ..\CMakeListsPath -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="..\installPath"**. Initially I was running this command from a bash script, but seeing the referenced question issue, I tried directly from the WSL terminal.

Comment: Oh, you forgot to **export** the variable defined in the `/etc/profile`. Without exporting the variable isn't propagated to the environment of the program(or script) called from the shell. See [that question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/difference-between-shell-variables-which-are-exported-and-those-which-are-not-in) about meaning of `export`. Note that the [question referenced by you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52504895/wsl-cant-see-environment-variable) contains exporting the variable.

Comment: You are completely right!. Thanks, since I was modifying /etc/environment at first I used the same syntax and forgot the export. It is now working.